# Slow Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, performance, com-interop, excel-interop

In my application I am automatically generating Excel file using C# code. This application is used on several environments (computers). On one computer generating this file is pretty slow than on all other computers.

For example following code is 90% slower on that computer:

```
        using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
        ...

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        Excel.Workbooks workbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
        Excel.Workbook xlBook = workbooks.Open(@"C:\a\a.xlsx", 0, false, 6, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");

        Excel.Range  oRange = xlSheet.get_Range(xlSheet.Cells[1, 1], xlSheet.Cells[2, 2]);

        object[,] a = new object[1, 1];
        a[0, 0] = "1";
        oRange.Value2 = a;

        xlBook.Save();

        xlApp.Visible = false;
        xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
```

get_Range method is 2 times slower on that machine.

Does anybody know how can I find out what is slowing down the comunication of Excel Interop COM object and what to do to make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of factors that could affect the performance of your interop code:

- Excel version
- .NET Framework version
- SDK version (if using VSTO)
- Presence/absence of service packs
- Hardware specs of the machine
- Resource usage (RAM, CPU, I/O, etc) at the time of execution
- Number of other COM applications installed on the machine

There are ways to speed up Excel interop code, such as hiding the window (you are already doing this) and setting the [`ScreenUpdating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx) property to false for the duration of the operation.

But, having said all this, COM interop is fundamentally slow and clunky. It is the least efficient way of working with Excel documents. You would be far better off using the [OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for this. It is 100% managed code and has no external dependencies (does not even require Office to be installed on the target machine).